# How to filter by partition using dbplyr and BigQuery

Tags: r, google-bigquery, dbplyr, bigrquery

I am connecting to BigQuery tables using `dbplyr` and the tables are partitioned, usually by date or time (the column is called _PARTITIONDATE or _PARTITIONTIME). In BigQuery, you can filter using the WHERE _PARTITIONDATE > "some date" to access segments of the table and improve query performance.

But when I connect to a table via `dbplyr`, there is no partition column on which to filter. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can use the `build_sql` function in `dbplyr` to filter on the partition column for the table and then continue to write your query using `dbplyr` e.g:

```
tbl(con, "table_name") %>%
filter(!!build_sql("DATE(_PARTITIONTIME > '2021-06-21'", con = con)
```

Whenever there is no `dbplyr` equivalent, you can do this.